# Make a Shortcode load after Post/Page Content?

Tags: shortcode, filters

I created a shortcode for `time.ly`'s "all in one event calendar app" that makes a paginated list of upcoming events with out all the java script and user options.

I posted [about it here](http://juliaallyce.wordpress.com/2012/07/30/creating-custom-agenda-shortcode-for-all-in-one-events-calendar/). *(Its still a work in progress)*

As it is now it loads before all the content, I'm guessing because the file returned at the end includes `echo`'s. I'd prefer if it always loaded after the posted content regardless of where it is typed on the page. Is it possible to force a short code to load after page content?

Comment: http://betterwp.net/17-protect-shortcodes-from-wpautop-and-the-likes/

After some more searching I found the above article. It is similar to how ai1ec handles their shortcodes as well...which means lots of regex. I'm hoping there is a simpler solution?

Comment: If you're having problems with wautop and shortcodes, make sure there's not another question about it already, and, if not, ask it separately.

Comment: My issue is not with wpautop. The article above shows how to find a shortcode in content using regex which could be used to get the short code to load outside of the content. I discovered this is similar to how time.ly makes there could load below post/page content. As I said before I was hoping there might be a simpler solution. In the mean time I've used buffering which I know is not ideal.

Comment: I've never tried this, but what if you put an action on `the_content` in the shortcode and then just return `$content . $something_else`?

Answer (score 7):

The contents of a shortcode should always be `return`ed rather than `echo`ed. You can read more about [shortcode output on the Codex](http://codex.wordpress.org/Shortcode_API#Output).

A while ago, I asked a question about ["How to Return Loop Contents"](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/57000/how-to-return-loop-contents) that might prove useful in this situation.

Comment: Your post was the golden one for me. I was baffled because my code did parse in admin but not in frontend, now I know why ;-) I should read first before coding...

Answer (score 1):

You could use ajax to fetch the content after the page loads, then insert it into the dom where you want it.

Here are some links that should help:

http://codex.wordpress.org/AJAX

http://codex.wordpress.org/AJAX_in_Plugins

http://www.garyc40.com/2010/03/5-tips-for-using-ajax-in-wordpress/

HTH

Comment: Do you have any examples of this? I'm not very familiar with using ajax :\

Comment: I don't have specific examples atm but here is a tutorial on how to do pagination using ajax to get the next set of posts - http://wp.tutsplus.com/articles/getting-started-with-ajax-wordpress-pagination/

Answer (score 0):

Just run  `do_shortcode($returned_content)` from the plugin, and it will run all shortcode filters on the content.

i.e.

Plugin:  MyPlugin.php

```
function some_func(){
     $data = "[tabs][tab]Tabbed content here[/tab][/tabs]";
     return $data;    
 }
```

The above function will return the data literally. without the shortcodes being parsed.  If you want to parse the shortcodes for display, simply do this:

```
function some_func(){
     $data = "[tabs][tab]Tabbed content here[/tab][/tabs]";
     return do_shortcode($data);    
 }
```

This example will parse the shortcodes before return.