# If post has non-shortcode string

Tags: posts, shortcode

I’m trying to load CSS/JS when the post contains specific text. Lets say when string `table` present, load additional CSS/JS.

`has_shortcode` is good but not works for non-shortcode string. Using `has_term` is possible but tedious.

Below is `has_shortcode` function for reference:

```
function loadmyshortcode() {
    global $post;
    if( is_a( $post, 'WP_Post' ) && has_shortcode( $post->post_content, 'my-shortcode') ) {
        wp_enqueue_script( 'idnamehere', get_template_directory_uri() . '/js/my-shortcode.js', array(), '', true );
    }
}
add_action( 'wp_enqueue_scripts', 'loadmyshortcode');
```

Comment: This is a basic PHP question, search for "PHP find string".

Comment: Do "WordPress way" if possible. I'm asking here to know if there is available way in WordPress. If not available, just say "not available in WordPress". Just because not available in WordPress, it is bad to say that way or downvote

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's indeed a basic PHP question. Use `strpos()`. Example:

```
if ( false !== strpos( $post->post_content, 'foo' ) ) {
    wp_enqueue_script();
}
```

Ps. I suggest you to not hook into `wp_enqueue_scripts()` but a later hooks, e.g. `the_content` and then load the JavaScript in the footer. This works best under all circumstances as `wp_enqueue_scripts` and `wp_head` are called way earlier before the post content is loaded/displayed.

See [How to add stylesheets only to pages with specific shortcode?](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/108444/how-to-add-stylesheets-only-to-pages-with-specific-shortcode) for an explanation on this as this question here is basically a duplicate.