# Why function hooked using object are executing at all time?

Tags: plugins, plugin-development, shortcode, oop

I tried to use class and object in plugin. I made a simple function with a `shortcode` but it is  executing the function without pasting the shortcode to any page/post.

```
class example{

function ex_funct(){
      ?>
      <h3>Hello</h3>
      <?php
}

}
$obj = new example();
add_shortcode('examp_code',$obj->ex_funct());
```

Why it is showing Hello at admin as well front end header without pasting the code `examp_code` ?

What is happening here?

Comment: A little side note, don't forget to capitalize the first letter when stating a class. `class Example` & `new Example();`

Comment: @Bobby, that is a convention. It is a common one and one adopted by WordPress Core development, but it is a convention nonetheless. It is not required by PHP.

Comment: I don't know why i got minus vote. @s_ha_dum is helped me which means this is okay. But i don't know who did this and why he did this

Comment: I don't know what you mean by "@s_ha_dum is helped me". I didn't help. I just made a comment about another user's comment. And even had I made a comment that helped it doesn't make the question OK. I often comment on questions/answers even if they substandard. At any rate, downvotes are anonymous (even to mods), but hover over the down arrow and you will see "This question does not show any research effort...". I am fairly sure that is the reason for the downvote. You have a PHP object syntax problem and two shortcode ones. Research into either of those would have gotten you a long way.

Comment: I don't know what others think but anyway, thanks for your help and explanation about this. I very much appreciate you. Thanks @s_ha_dum

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That happens, because you *run* the function in `add_shortcode()`. To send is as callback, use:

```
add_shortcode('examp_code', array ( $obj, 'ex_funct' ) );
```

Now you have still a problem: you create output in your shortcode callback. Never do that, you [have to return a string](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/a/73083/73).

Change it to:

```
function ex_funct(){
      return '<h3>Hello</h3>';
}
```

Comment: Thanks. +1 any other different way to hook functions with object? just want to know is there some other way exists:)

Comment: @rram No, that’s the only way.