# latest posts shortcode with image

Tags: shortcode

I am trying to make a shortcode that will take my latest 5 posts and render them on page. I get all the posts rendered correctly except for the image source, I receive it blank. Is it something I'm doing wrong?

```
$content = $content?$content:'Latest Posts';
$a = shortcode_atts(
    array(
        'posts'=>5
    ),
    $atts
);
$args = array('numberposts'=>$a['posts']);
$recent_posts = wp_get_recent_posts( $args, ARRAY_A );
echo '<div class="recent-posts">';
echo '<h1>'.$content.'</h1>';
foreach($recent_posts as $post){
    ?>
    <div class="updated"><p><?php echo $post['post_title']; ?>. <a href="<?php echo get_permalink($post["ID"]); ?>"><img src="<?php the_post_thumbnail_url($post["ID"]); ?>"/>.</a></p></div>
    <?php
}
 echo '</div>';
}
```

Comment: You [must not use `echo`](http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/73082/shortcode-outputs-at-the-top-of-the-content) in a shortcode callback.

Comment: Omg, I will never program during night, banged my head off the walls for 30 minutes but missed such a basic thing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

#### Image fix

You are using the incorrect function to return the image source url. Change

```
the_post_thumbnail_url( $post["ID"] )
```

to

```
get_the_post_thumbnail_url( $post["ID"] )
```

see https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/get_the_post_thumbnail_url/

#### To fix the echo

Use a *$return* variable like so:

```
$out = '<div class="recent-posts">';
$out .= '<h1>'.$content.'</h1>';
foreach($recent_posts as $post){
    $out .= '<div class="updated"><p>' . $post['post_title'] . '.<a href="' . get_permalink($post['ID']) . '">';
    $out .= '<img src="' . get_the_post_thumbnail_url( $post['ID'] ) . "'/>.</a></p></div>';
}
$out .= '</div>';

return $out;
```

Comment: Thanks man, I missed a basic thing, that I was looking for more than 30 minutes :D

Comment: @Radu033 if this was your solution, would you care to mark it as such?