# Create shortcode to echo javascript

Tags: plugins, plugin-development, shortcode, jquery, wp-enqueue-script

I have this typed.js code snippet, which I want to call from a shortcode:

```
<script src="https://www.example.com/wp-content/themes/mediso-v1-03/javascript/jquery-2.2.4.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://www.example.com/wp-content/themes/mediso-v1-03/javascript/typed.js"></script>

<script>// <![CDATA[
$(function(){ $(".element-typing").typed({ strings: ["This is my typing text"], typeSpeed: 20 }); });
// ]]></script>
<p class="element-typing"></p>
```

Here is what I came up with:

```
// Add Shortcode
function custom_shortcode23() {
    wp_enqueue_script('script-typed-jquery', 'https://www.example.com/wp-content/themes/mediso-v1-03/jquery-2.2.4.min.js', array('jquery'));
    wp_enqueue_script('script-typed', 'https://www.example.comwp-content/themes/mediso-v1-03/typed.js', array('jquery'));
    echo    '<script>// <![CDATA[$(function(){ $(".element-typing").typed({ strings: ["This is my typing text"], typeSpeed: 20 }); });',
    '// ]]></script>',
    '<p class="element-typing"></p>';
}
add_shortcode( 'typed23', 'custom_shortcode23' );
```

But it is not working. Where am I wrong?

Comment: A shortcode callback [must return a string](http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/73082/shortcode-outputs-at-the-top-of-the-content), not `echo` anything.

Answer (score 6):

First of all, it looks like you are trying to enqueue version 2.2.4 of jquery, under the condition that jquery has already been loaded. That doesn't look good.

Secondly, you can't just echo a script in a shortcode. You must add it to another script using [`wp_add_inline_script`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/wp_add_inline_script/). Like this:

```
function wpse238227_custom_shortcode23() {
    wp_enqueue_script('script-typed', 'https://www.example.comwp-content/themes/mediso-v1-03/typed.js', array('jquery'));
    // script needs to be added
    $script_to_add = 'jQuery(function ($) { $(".element-typing").typed({ strings: ["This is my typing text"], typeSpeed: 20 }); });';
    wp_add_inline_script ('script-typed', $script_to_add);
    // the html needs to be returned
    return "<p class='element-typing'></p>";
}
add_shortcode( 'typed23', 'wpse238227_custom_shortcode23' );
```

Note that this script will be added to the footer, because by the time WordPress is evaluating the shortcode in the content, the head of the site has already been assembled. You may also want to read [more about enqueueing scripts from shortcodes](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/165754/enqueue-scripts-styles-when-shortcode-is-present) in general.

Comment: We actually don't need the `<script>` tag with `wp_add_inline_script()`.

Comment: True, and the paragraph tag can't be just there either because it isn't a script. I just copied the whole string too quikcly.

Comment: We should probably use `jQuery(function ($) {...});` too.

Comment: @birgire Why are you always right? ;-)