# the_content() not showing the content in good order (with a shortcode)

Tags: shortcode, html, the-content

I've added a shortcode [form] inside my wysiwyg the 2 paragraphes before the shortcode.

```
<p>test 1</p>

<p>test2</p>

[form]
```

but on the frontend, the shortcode is showing at the top of the content. I thought it was an error in CSS, but the HTML is indead rendering the form, and then my paragraph.

Any idea? I'm on WP 5.4

EDIT :

This is how the shortcode is created :

```
/* SHORTCODE */
function form_shortcode() {
    include( "includes/form.php" );
    return;
}

add_shortcode( 'form_calcul', 'form_shortcode' );
```

I have a few lines of php inside. I should probably precise, I'm in a plugin. I tried also this, but no success:

```
    ob_start();
get_template_part('form');
return ob_get_clean();
```

Comment: Obviously, this depends on what the shortcode does, but since you didn't include its code, it's impossible to tell.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Shortcode outputs at the top of the\_content](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/73082/shortcode-outputs-at-the-top-of-the-content)

Comment: The shortcode is showing a form surounded by a div

Answer (score 0):

Before `the_content` is displayed WP looks for filters to run the content through. One of those filters is [`do_shortcode`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/do_shortcode/). The idea of a filter is that you can change something before it is displayed. As a consequence, if inside the filter function you echo something, it ends up before `the_content`, which is still waiting for the filtering process to be completed.

Since your function `form_shortcode()` does not return a modified `content` anything that is displayed must be the result of `echo` statements in `form.php`.